# Javascript : Pass String by value

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem with one of my javascript code. Here is the code

```
//assume array is an array containing strings and myDiv, some div in my doc
for(var i in array) {
    var myString = array[i];
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerHTML = myString;
    a.addEventListener("click", function() {myFunc(myString)}, false);
    myDiv.appendChild(a)
}
function myFunc(s) {alert(s);}
```

However, since Strings are passed by reference in JavaScript, I see always the last string of my `array` when I click on the link `a` in question. Thus, my question is "How can I pass `myString` by value ?". Thank you for your help !
Phil

Comment: never iterate over an array using `for...in`.

Comment: _MY EYES_ `addEventListener` allows you to _delegate_ an event, rather then binding it to each and every element individually, you're doing both and therefore neither: the worst of two worlds... + `addEventListener` isn't supported by IE <9

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem you're right about the delegation, although using a delegated handler still leaves him with the problem of how to find the appropriate data for the target of the event.

Comment: I know, that's why I merely commented your solution would be my suggestion. With IE<9 supported: `if (a.addEventListener){a.addEventlistener('click',make_callback(myString),false);} else { a.attachEvent('onclick',make_callback(myString));}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a closure around your event handler:

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

```
a.addEventListener("click", function (s) {
    return function () {
        alert(s)
    };
}(myString), false);
```

Also, you should not use `for...in` loops on arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Primitive variables are *not* passed by reference in Javascript.

This is the classic 'loop variable called inside a closure' problem.

Here's one commonly-used solution to that problem:

```
for (var i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var myString = array[i];
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerHTML = myString;
    a.addEventListener("click", make_callback(myString), false);
    myDiv.appendChild(a)
}

function make_callback(s) {
     return function() {
         alert(s);
     }
}
```

Note that this isn't particularly memory efficient since it creates a new function scope for *every* element in the array.

A better solution might be to store the variable data actually on the element (i.e. as a new property) and retrieve that in the callback.  In fact you're already storing that string in the `.innerHTML` property so you could just read that and then take advantage of *delegation* to register just the one handler on the elements' parent:

```
for (var i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerHTML = array[i];
    myDiv.appendChild(a)
}

myDiv.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    alert(ev.target.innerHTML);
}, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :
i think its always good not practice to iterate array using for...in

```
for(var i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
    var myString = array[i];
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerHTML = myString;
    a.addEventListener("click", function() {myFunc(myString)}, false);
    myDiv.appendChild(a)
}
function myFunc(s) {alert(s);}
```

Comment: this is a good change, but it does nothing to address the problem he's looking to solve.